# use div instead of table to align my text

Tags: html, css

I want to use div instead of table , I want to have the text aligned like the a following image

[image]

instead of

[image]

**Update:**
it works fine :

```
<div style=" display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:200px;padding:10px;float:left;">Event name:</div>

    <div style=" width:600px;padding:8px; ">{{ event.name }}</div>
</div>

<div style=" display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:200px;padding:10px;float:left;">Field :</div>

    <div style=" width:600px;padding:8px; ">{{ event.field}}</div>
</div>

<div style=" display:inline-block;">

    <div style="width:200px;padding:10px;float:left;">Event address :</div>

    <div style=" width:600px;padding:8px; ">{{ event.address }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take [the tour](/tour) and read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Also try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) that reproduces the above issue.

Comment: ok I will delete my question and try myself then ask

Comment: You can also edit it!

Comment: regarding your "update": actually I meant it the other way round in my answer: Make the inner DIVs inline blocks and leave the wrapping DIVs as is (default: block) - no need for floats.

Comment: I have corrected my code thank you PS:even the other code work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to achieve that is to apply `display: inline-block` and  fixed `width` values to those DIV blocks. (And wrap them into parent DIVs in groups of two)